# Does RocketMQ support master-slave auto switch?

Tags: rocketmq

Does RocketMQ support master-slave auto switch?
I have try it in v3.5.8, but it does not work. So, i just want ask someone who can gave accuracy answer

Answer (score 2):

No, Rocketmq does not support this for sending messages.

Howerver, slave can take the position for pulling messages when master is out of service. And auto switch to slave for reading has been implemented.

So problems only exist in the scenario of sending messsages, if you need to have high-availability on writing, please put more master with diffrent group name in service.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Rocketmq  Version 5.0.0